# Risks of using OData and IQueryable

Tags: javascript, linq, odata, iqueryable, breeze

I have seen many tutorials about making SPA (single page application) and many of them uses an external library such as breezejs and jaydatajs in order to get an automated dataservice layer.

These libraries expect that I'll expose an IQueryable object that they can query.

My question is, what are the risks of exposing an IQueryable from the server? I want the know if making this shortcut with those js libraries worth it, or should I expose my own functions in the server and implement the dataservice myself in the client.

The thing is, when exposing an Iqueryable, I can use breezejs, for example, to create queries for filtering and paging with linq like syntax. If I'll not use it, I will have to implement these functions for filtering and paging in the server. and implement the calls to them in the javascript.

I hope I was clear :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is one thing that I try to do when exposing IQueryable... make sure you do not expose your EF style objects, always make sure you have a view model of some sort sitting over the top that you can control.

Just as an example, say your DB has User and UserSecrets

```
public class User
{
    public long UserId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<UserSecret> UserSecrets { get; set; }
}

public class UserSecret
{
    public long UserSecretId { get; set; }
    public long UserId { get; set; }
    public string Secret { get; set; }
}
```

If you expose `IQueryable<User>` you can easily extract the UserSecrets as well

```
www.blah.com/users?$expand=UserSecrets
```

Instead expose a `UserViewModel` or something similar

```
public class UserViewModel
{
     public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

You can expose `IQueryable<UserViewModel>` in the following way:

```
return dbContext.Users.Select(u => new UserViewModel { Name = u.Name })
```

The great thing is that this is still `IQueryable` - you can still filter etc and it will still execute at the db level, but you have control over exactly what data can be pulled (in this case `UserSecret` is no longer accessible).

Of course you can also apply your own filters so you can avoid users not getting access to data they are not allowed too:

```
return dbContext.Users.Where(u => ...).Select(u => new UserViewModel { Name = u.Name })
```

Comment: OK, seems like a good solution, So what you are saying is that instead of exposing DB entities, I should expose only projections of these entities.

Comment: Yes, and pre-filter your queries if required as well

Comment: This solution doesn't handle the more complicated problem of some users being able to see the user secrets and some not.

Answer (score 0):

It's seen to be that you create the DTO object for projection the entity object and try to make the  essential properties on this DTO. This action will make we secure for our own information that expose from database and avoid bleeding some secret information from service side out to client.