# Linq security - hide columns

Tags: linq, security, breeze

I am struggling a bit on what probably is a simple matter or something I misunderstand... But anyway, using Linq entity code first, I am trying to keep some of my tables to be inaccessible from the client, without success.

Using Breeze, I have made a datacontext that holds only the dbsets I want exposed, fine.
But when I write a query using .expand(). For example, let's say I have a posts table which I want to expose, and an Owner table that I want to hide.
Using a query like:

```
var query = EntityQuery
            .from('Posts')
            .expand('Owner');
```

I can still see all the columns from Owner.

So the question is: in Linq, how am I supposed to secure/protect/hide the tables, and/or specific columns, that I want to hide?

After some digging, all I have found is the [JsonIgnore] attribute, which seems insufficient to me.

What is the best way to do this? I feel I am missing something probably huge here, but it's the end of the day around here...

Thanks

Comment: Why does the client have access to the model at all?

Comment: This is how Breeze works: it sends metadata to the client, based on the DbContext, to make queries easier to write.

Comment: And yet, the question remains.  Why are you sending the metadata to the client with table info that you don't want them to access?  Make a different DbContext that only contains the tables and fields that should be accessible from the client seems like a reasonable solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the Breeze's WebApi implementation then Breeze also supports ODataQueryOptions ( [see here](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/supporting-odata-query-options#limiting_query_options) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.odata.query.allowedqueryoptions%28v=vs.111%29.aspx) ).

This allows you to mark up your controller methods so as to limit how the query is interpreted. For example, to only allow filtering on your 'Posts' query and therefore exclude the ability to "expand" or "select" 'Owners' from any 'Posts' request you could do the following.

```
[Queryable(AllowedQueryOptions=AllowedQueryOptions.Filter| AllowedQueryOptions.Top | AllowQueryOptions.Skip)]
public IQueryable<Posts> Posts() {
  ....
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Ok apparently my question was already addressed here:
[Risks of using OData and IQueryable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15762502/risks-of-using-odata-and-iqueryable)

I just found it.

Comment: Also check John Papa's post here: http://www.johnpapa.net/spajs04 and in the comments, the question asked by Martin where he mentions DTO's. Straight to the point.

Comment: Other interesting blog post on a related subject http://neverindoubtnet.blogspot.be/2013/02/the-breeze-server-it-your-way.html